# dual axis tableau chart into powerbi

Tags: powerbi

I am using nycflights13 and trying to make the same tableau bar chart in power bi.

In Tableau this can be done using a dual-axis chart. How to do it in power bi?

the sample data set would be something below

```
Carriers   City     Country  
Ev          61        30
UA          47        30
9E          49        24
```

If I plot based on the distinct city and country separately, get the following plot:[image]

If I merge the plots above, using dual axis (in tableau), and made the country bar chart transparent, I get the one below which I would like to able to do it using power bi. Is there a way to get the plot below using power bi?
[image]

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In Power BI you can use the Clustered Bar Chart

[image]

Or write a measure that is Cities-Countries and use that instead of Countries in a stacked bar chart

[image]